# PositionToCoords for RichTextCtrl

Tags: wxpython, textctrl, richtextctrl

I have been using the PositionToCoords() method to convert the text cursor position to window coordinates in the TextCtrl widget.

Now, I have to move to using the RichTextCtrl widget but PositionToCoords() is not available there and I cannot find an equivalent method.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you thinking of `PositionToXY` and `XYToPosition`

Comment: PositionToXY() didn't work. I am trying to get a popup menu follow the text cursor -- and PositionToXY (GetInsertionPoint() pops up the menu at the top left of the window. The official docs (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_text_ctrl.html) don't mention any reason why it shouldn't.